# Getting Whatsapp Backup file from Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, whatsapp

I am currently using the below script to get regular files from Google Drive. It works fine and its basically the code from the user @user115202 cudos.

Now I need to get it to work for Whatsapp Backups which are stored under "Backup" in GoogleDrive and not as a regular file.

The tool WhatsApp Google Drive Extractor (Google Drive API) doesnt seem to work anymore.

Does anyone know an alternative?

```
import requests

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    def get_confirm_token(response):
        for key, value in response.cookies.items():
            if key.startswith('download_warning'):
                return value

        return None

    def save_response_content(response, destination):
        CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

        with open(destination, "wb") as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
                if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)

    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) is not 3:
        print "Usage: python google_drive.py drive_file_id destination_file_path"
    else:
        # TAKE ID FROM SHAREABLE LINK
        file_id = sys.argv[1]
        # DESTINATION FILE ON YOUR DISK
        destination = sys.argv[2]
        download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, destination)
```

Comment: I managed to tackle the API and made some changes in the code and it works now. code will be available on https://github.com/EliteAndroidApps/WhatsApp-GD-Extractor/

Answer (score 5):

I managed to tackle the API and made some changes in the code and it works now. The code will be available on https://github.com/EliteAndroidApps/WhatsApp-GD-Extractor